# Adding multiple images and strings to Table View Cells in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

## Problem:

What I am attempting to do is format my table view cells like so:

```
[IMG]   CELL_NAME    [IMG]STRING   [IMG]STRING
```

I have figured out how to add a header image and a name for the cell, but I am having trouble figuring out how to add in the two remaining images with the attached strings. (view above)

## viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Upgrades" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    upgrades = [dict objectForKey:@"UpgradeStrings"];
    thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"UpgradeImages"];

    _regularBubbleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
    _premiumBubbleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount];
}
```

## cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Handles appearance of cells in table.

    static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [upgrades objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add the images and labels as custom subviews.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Check out this tutorial to get started: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" for information about creating custom cells.